# Imagea doesn't load

Tags: html, image, github, sass

For some reason my images doesn't load when I open my project through Github. It says the file can't be found.

However, when I open the project through VS Code Live server, it's completely fine. Does anyone happen to know why this is happening?

Github Repository: https://github.com/nmukassa1/designo

Project: https://nmukassa1.github.io/designo/

Answer (score -1):

It seems you are trying to load the images from:

```
<img src="/assets/home/desktop/illustration-passionate.svg" alt="illustration">
```

when deployed to github, ends up with the url:

```
https://nmukassa1.github.io/assets/home/desktop/illustration-passionate.svg
```

This is incorrect since the site is not located under the root-url but under the /designo path.

Try loading the image with

```
    <img src="./assets/home/desktop/illustration-passionate.svg" alt="illustration">
```

notice the . in the start of the src-attribute.
this will load the images from

```
https://nmukassa1.github.io/designo/assets/home/desktop/illustration-passionate.svg
```

Comment: You're a G. Appreciate the help. Been stuck on this issue for a while. Much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

you delete first " / "
examples: assets/home/desktop/illustration-passionate.svg"  ;
assets/home/desktop/illustration-resourceful.svg"